# android open files from url

Tags: java, android, google-docs

I am having some trouble opening few files. I have database where is description about file (id, name, type and etc). These files originaly are saved in another folder on server. Is it possible to open them if I know only url like: http://**************/resource/view.php?id=11 ? I manage to open some files using webview, but I need to open also pdf files. By the way is it possible to open doc files on google view? because I tried and it did not opened it but it opened pdf file in next try.

Comment: you have to download the pdf and launch an intent to open the pdf reader.

Comment: It is more elaborate, but you could use Google Docs API to open the files. https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#what_can_this_api_do

Answer (score 0):

```
WebView urlWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.containWebView);
urlWebView.setWebViewClient(new AppWebViewClients());
urlWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
urlWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
urlWebView.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="
            + "YOUR_DOC_URL_HERE"); 

public class AppWebViewClients extends WebViewClient {

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);

}
```

}